# Error al compilar, "module-info.java", proyecto javafx con maven

Tags: java, javafx, maven, intellij-idea

Para comenzar estoy trabajando en "Intellij IDEA", JDK 11, Maven, JavaFX

Hace algunos dias, tuve que arreglar mi proyecto javafx con maven, ya que quise emplear el patrón de diseño vista, modelo, controlador.
en la creación de los packages todo iba bien, hasta que me salta un error en el module-info.java, lo cual no le tome importancia y lo eliminé, al poco tiempo no me compilaba correctamente etonces decidí recuperar ese "module-info.java" pero algo andaba mal, me saltaba error, en el main.java y también en el module-info, estuve buscando problemas similares y no encontré nada, por eso quiero que me ayuden por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las diferentes carpetas como com/community/poo/controller , com/community/poo/data , com/community/poo/model fueron creadas por mi ya que quise distribuir bien el código empelando el patrón MVC.

Ahora en el resource/com/community/poo/view , se encuentras los archivos con extensiones ".fxml"

```
module com.community.poo {

  requires javafx.controls;
  requires javafx.fxml;

  opens com.community.poo to javafx.fxml;
  exports com.community.poo;
}
```

La imagen que se encuentra arriba es el código del "module-info.java", como les decía, una vez distribuida las diferentes clases de controller, vista y modelo, me saltó ERROR en el "module-info.java"

Y ahora les muestro el código de mi "Main" donde me salta error al cargar el archivo, cuya ubicación se encuentra en "resource/com/community/poo/view", y dentro de ella hay un archivo "primary.fxml" la cual llamo, pero parece que no reconoce bien la ruta.

```
package com.community.poo.model;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class App extends Application {

private static Scene scene;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    scene = new Scene(loadFXML("view/primary"), 640, 480);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
    scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
}

private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + 
".fxml"));
    return fxmlLoader.load();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
}
```

Por favor necesito la ayuda, les agradecería bastante.

---> si hay una documentación donde explica todo esto estaria agradecido, o tal vez una mejor forma de emplear el patron MVC con maven y a la vez en proyecto JavaFX.

Comment: Por favor, añade texto en lugar de imágenes para los trozos de código. Es más legible y además se puede copiar a la respuesta con facilidad para indicar cualquier error o proponer arreglos. Te invito a que completes el [tour] para conocer cómo se espera en SOes que se formulen las preguntas

Comment: ya se editó, amigo gracias-

me puedes ayudar con mi problema por favor

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te da? En la imagen anterior se veía subrayado el exports, pero no se veía el mensaje de error.

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro 100%, pero creo que tienes problemas con los paths:

- En el `module-info` intentas declarar como exportable un paquete vacío:

  ```
    exports com.community.poo;
  ```

  Pero los paquete hijos (por ejemplo `com.community.poo.model`) no están incluídos en esa exportación, has de declararlos explícitamente.
- En tu clase App, haces referencia a un fichero fxml con `view/primary.fxml`, pero tu clase está en el paquete `com.community.poo.model`, con lo que el path resultante es `com/community/poo/model/view/primary.xml`, tendrías que poner `../` como prefijo.