package javax.persistence is declared in module java.persistence, but module does not read it
Tengo problemas para importar @Entity en proyecto de maven fxml javafx
package java;

@Entity
public class NewClass {
    
    @Id
    private String dni;
    
    
}

Añado las dependencias pero de todas formas no puedo importar los paquetes necesarios para las anotaciones.
intenté con import javax.persistence.*; y con import jakarta.persistence.*; ambos arrojan como mensaje en la info:

package javax.persistence is not visible (package javax.persistence is declared in module java.persistence, but module com.mycompany.proyectofacultad does not read it)


con que import instentaste? puedes compartir tu pom para saber que version de JavaEE o spring usas?

Buenas, intenté con import javax.persistence.; y con import jakarta.persistence.; ambos arrojan como mensaje en la info :package javax.persistence is not visible (package javax.persistence is declared in module java.persistence, but module com.mycompany.proyectofacultad does not read it)

Algo me dice que está relacionado con jigsaw y los archivos moduleinfo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/408006/error-al-compilar-module-info-java-proyecto-javafx-con-maven?rq=1

Hola, lo solucioné agregando    : requires jakarta.persistence;     en la clase module-info.java

De todas formas no agrega la clase a la cual le pongo la anotación Entity a la unidad  persistence.xml, alguien que pueda darme una mano con el tema ...

te recomiendo responder tu propia pregunta, ya que esa es la solución común a ese problema y después hacer otra pregunta en el que expliques a detalle a que te refieres con que "no agrega". saludos.

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? ¿Qué es el module-info de java y para qué se utiliza?
